# check_box with fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, nested-attributes, fields-for

Here's the code

```
= f.fields_for :category do |fc|
  = fc.check_box :is_visible
```

I've ran into the situation described here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box `Unfortunately that workaround does not work when the check box goes within an array-like parameter, as in ...`

What happens is that when updating the model with the checkbox unchecked, the is_visible stays as true. This problem is documented and the proposed fix is `In that case it is preferable to either use check_box_tag or to use hashes instead of arrays.`

I have no clue how to implement the solution. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works and the problem was `Unpermitted parameters: visible`.

Permitting `visible` in the controller fixed this.